# Shopware 6 custom CMS element

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I am creating a custom element. I do the steps correctly according to this [document](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element), but I can not update my config value.

here is my code.

> customelement/index.js

```
import './component'; 
import './preview';
import './config';
Shopware.Service('cmsService').registerCmsElement({
   name: 'customelement',
   label: 'sw-cms.elements.customelement.label',
   component: 'sw-cms-el-customelement',
   configComponent: 'sw-cms-el-config-customelement',
   previewComponent: 'sw-cms-el-preview-customelement',
   defaultConfig: {
      varName: {
        source: 'static',
        value: 'hello raj'
     }
  }
});
```

> customelement/component/index.js

```
import template from './sw-cms-el-customelement.html.twig';
import './sw-cms-el-customelement.scss';
Shopware.Component.register('sw-cms-el-customelement', {
    template,

    mixins: [
      'cms-element'
    ],

  computed: {
      varName() {
          return this.element.config.varName.value;
      }
  },

  created() {
      this.createdComponent();
  },

  methods: {
      createdComponent() {
           this.initElementConfig('customelement');
      }
  }
});
```

> customelement/config/index.js

```
import template from './sw-cms-el-config-customelement.html.twig';
Shopware.Component.register('sw-cms-el-config-customelement', {
   template,

   mixins: [
      'cms-element'
   ],

   computed: {
      varName() {
         return this.element.config.varName.value;
      }
   },

   created() {
      this.createdComponent();
   },

   methods: {
      createdComponent() {
         this.initElementConfig('customelement');
      },

      onElementUpdate(element) {
         this.$emit('element-update', element);
      }
  }
});
```

> customelement/config/sw-cms-el-config-customelement.html.twig

```
{% block sw_cms_element_customelement_config %}
<sw-text-field
    class="swag-customelement-field"
    label="value"
    placeholder="Enter value..."
    v-model="varName"
    @element-update="onElementUpdate">
</sw-text-field>
{% endblock %}
```

When I enter a varName value and press done the varName value is set to the default value.
Is there anything wrong? If not, then why the config value is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if the documentation is correct. I think it might be that `onElementUpdate` isn't called. Maybe try using the conventional event binds and set the value manually:

```html
<sw-text-field
    class="swag-customelement-field"
    label="value"
    placeholder="Enter value..."
    v-model="varName"
    @input="onElementUpdate"
    @change="onElementUpdate">
</sw-text-field>
```

```js
// sw-cms-el-config-customelement
onElementUpdate(value) {
    this.element.config.varName.value = value;

    this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
}
```